# Drupal 7 auto update from data from table or?

Tags: php, drupal-modules

I am learning to make site with Drupal 7 and everything is fine and to my liking. 

i have a script written in Perl which scrapes news from a website. 

**Now i want Drupal to (run the script if possible otherwise i can use server corn job to do it) update front page of site by making page or article from each scraped news.** 

I can always add data from perl to db, xml, csv or JSON file. It is just automation required. Please guide me to the possible solution e.g. if i need to write a script in PHP where and how should i include it in the Drupal or if there is any module you found helpful (there are lots of modules to search through but looking in the right driection which i am lacking).
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) to import nodes from a csv file. You can put the data you're scraping into a csv and have the import run automatically at a set interval.

Comment: thanks but Do you know that (just wondering) if i can instruct drupal to run Perl script?

Comment: I don't know, but it sounds like it would be simpler to just run the perl script with cron.